# Capture console output into variable?

Tags: bash, bitcoin

How could I capture the console output into a variable when running a utility so I can filter the text?

---

**Example:** I am trying to capture the console output when I type `bitcoind`  so that I can filter out the *rpcpassword* and write it to a config file.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-49:~$ bitcoind
Error: To use bitcoind, you must set a rpcpassword in the configuration file:
/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
It is recommended you use the following random password:
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=Eb5WDgzKqt77U4LhvvfnYxaNvw2rpztSvM5XKsonXBWC
(you do not need to remember this password)
The username and password MUST NOT be the same.
If the file does not exist, create it with owner-readable-only file permissions.
It is also recommended to set alertnotify so you are notified of problems;
for example: alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "Bitcoin Alert" admin@foo.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the output to a file e.g.

```
bitcoind >~/bitcoind_output.txt 2>&1
```

This will put the output in a file in your home directory called bitcoind_output.txt

Comment: Cheers Glenn - well spotted with the typo :)

Comment: You'll want the `2>&1` after the `>~/bitcoind_output.txt`.

Comment: @minerz029 That was the trick `bitcoind >~/bitcoind_output.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

To capture the output into a variable:

```
output=$(bitcoind 2>&1)
```

Comment: curious: what does the variable hold, and what goes to the screen?